# I am having issues linking my view to a stylesheet

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing a tutorial which seems to be based off of an older version of Rails (Agile Web Dev using Rails), and I seem to be unable to link a view with a stylesheet I made.

Here is my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Depot</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag   :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

And I added a CSS file named `depot.css` under `app/assets/stylesheets`, however the style changes made in the file are not applied.

I'm new to this, and if there's any information required to help figure this out, do let me know. I am running Rails 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try renaming 'depot.css' to 'depot.css.scss'.

Also, check your application.css.scss and make sure it has something like this:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

Comment: I renamed depot, to no effect. `application.css.scss` does include those lines, they are commented however, is this as it should be?

Comment: Have you have `config.assets.compress = false` set in your development.rb config? And are you are using the development environment? Also try checking the head tags on any page request to see if `depot.css` is being included.